# How to format multiple items in list in python

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I'm accessing a list via an API by using this:

```
tags = result["data"]["product"]["tags"]
```

Which produces this result:

```
['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
```

I found a way to format them the way I want, but it only works in the console. In my main code I'm using a Discord embed and here is the embed field:

```
embed.add_field(name="Tags:", value="{}".format(tags), inline=False)
```

Using this method (works only in console):

```
print(*tags, sep=' | ')
```

Which prints them like this:

```
item1 | item2 | item3
```

But as soon as I try that method in the Discord embed, it only prints the first item and nothing else.
I want to be able to get what I got in the console onto my discord embed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the join function to achieve this. It takes an iterable and we can pass in elements from our list into here. See the example below:

```
items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']

embed = discord.Embed(title="My Embed")
embed.add_field(name="Tags:", value=f"{' | '.join([x for x in items])}", inline=False)
```